# Writing a stored procedure in Cassandra database

Tags: java, stored-procedures, cassandra

I am a senior database developer having extreme experience with all major relational databases (Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL,...), but I am new to NoSQL world. Recently my company decided to use Apache Cassandra database. I am learning this now for a few weeks, and have come up with following question:

Q> Can we create a stored procedure or function in Cassandra database? if yes,  does Cassandra provide its own programming language (Like Oralce's PL/SQL) ? if it does not have a language of its own, what language can we use? is it Java? if it is Java, do we need to install Java separately? or it is installed with Cassandra and is built into it, ready to be used in stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

You can write [user defined functions](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/user-defined-functions-in-cassandra-3-0/) or triggers (possibly materialized views). UDFs are really just to simplify reading things which is probably not what you're looking for. It really depends on what you want to do, I would recommend against triggers unless you're a very advanced cassandra user. Materialized views could provide what you want, if your trying to allow multiple ways to look at the data.

Really the design taken is to move that out of the database and into your application.  Keep in mind that the idea is to denormalize, not normalize your data. Generally when designing a schema for Cassandra you end up creating a table per query you make, and than when inserting your data you make many inserts to all the relevant tables. There is plenty of [free training](https://academy.datastax.com/) and videos available for data modeling. I suggest spending a lot of time going through it before building your data model to save from misconceptions and gotchas later.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. One more question, if we can write UDFs or triggers in Cassandra, what language do we use for writing the code? if it is Java, can we write like a simple Java function, or, we must create a Java class?, also how do we compile the code? does Cassandra has built in support for Java so that it can handle compiling itself?

Comment: By default, Cassandra 2.2 and later supports defining functions in java and javascript. Other scripting languages, such as Python, Ruby, and Scala can be added by adding a JAR to the classpath. For triggers you need to write it in java and include a jar in the classpath (I recommend staying away from triggers! they are for advanced use cases, general use of them likely means you designed your schema wrong).